# Can same GUID produce different hash codes?

Tags: c#, .net, guid, hashcode, .net-4.6.2

Given same *GUID* `Object.GetHashCode` produces different hash codes but `Object.Equals` shows that same GUID equals.

The whole GUID:

[image]

Not same hash code:

[image]

Equals `==` `true`:

[image]

And, obviously, both are `System.Guid`:

[image]

Even when it's the same GUID, they're different values as they are deserialized from two sources.

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: When two objects are equal their hashcodes should also be equal. This is the contract between the two methods. To achieve this they should both reflect the same members to be checked, which shouldn´t be the case in your scenario for whatever reason.

Comment: is this `System.Guid`? or some type that just looks similar? what is `tags.ToList()[0].GetType().FullName` and `existingTags.ToList()[2].GetType().FullName` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell Hey ;) They're GUIDs. but I can take a screenshot to clarify

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer do you know what's better than screenshots? code that we can run... I expect you'll find that the act of producing a minimal repro *actually allows you to find the problem yourself*

Comment: @MarcGravell Yep but the conditions to produce the result maybe aren't easy to reproduce in a single step

Comment: `Guid.Equals` looks quite innocent: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,54bcc19a4028b3f2

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer ineded, but currently we have *no reasonable way* of commenting; we can't see what the types are - and I can't even read the guid reliably to try to rule out a few things, perhaps tell you which one is misbehaving "more"

Comment: Please don't post illegible screenshots. Post *code*. You don't show the type in the screenshots. You may be looking at *different* objects whose Display String is a GUID

Comment: Something else is going on here. You can see in [the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,923) that all parts used to generate the hash code of a Guid are asserted to be equal in `Equals`. What you're claiming shouldn't be possible.

Comment: short version of an answer: "no, that shouldn't happen" - as to what you *are* seeing: we'd need more context (ideally code)

Comment: Two identical guids cannot produce different hash code, you should search the problem in another place

Comment: There's nothing strange aboug [Guid.GetHashCode](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs,923) either. The same Guids should produce the same hash code. At least post the *GUID* you used. Don't force us to increase the size to 200% just to type the characters

Comment: @CharlesMager slight caveat: even "impossible" things can happen routinely; the number of times I've found "impossible" things, and then found them to be a JIT or compiler error is ... well, low, admittedly, but: non-zero

Comment: Hold people, I'm asking if it's an expected behavior. It's very easy to answer this, it's not about the actual case but if there's a chance for this behavior or not.

Comment: In your "see, they're the same type" screenshot, you've added an indirection through an `.Id` property. So the types in the lists *aren't* guids, then have a guid accessible through `Id`.

Comment: Important: your recent edit **is different** - you're now looking at `.Id` there; you weren't originally; so presumably the `.Id` is the `Guid`, and the parent to that (which you are comparing) is **something else**

Comment: @MarcGravell fair enough ;). I've amended to 'shouldn't be possible'.

Comment: Before closing the Q&A, hold, I'm going to try if I can reproduce the issue in an isolated dotnetfiddle...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer the `type` screenshot shows an *ID*. Most likely you were looking at the debug display value for a `Tag` object all along. What does the tag's code look like? Does it have any debugger attributes?

Comment: @MarcGravell `[DebuggerDisplay]`

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer irrelevant! Since `Guid` doesn't have a `.Id` member, we know that `tags` is **not** a list of `Guid`, and neither is `existingTags`. The problem is in that declaring type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your test is incorrect. In the final part where you're comparing the `.GetType().FullName`, you are looking at the `.Id`, but that **is not** what you are comparing above that.

So: the problem is in whatever the type is that has a `.Id`, the thing that is in `tags` and `existingTags`. Look at the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` ***of that***.

Comment: Yeah yeah... It has been an epic fail.

Comment: And, at the end of the day, the Q&A irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

The screenshots do not show the *type* of the watched variable, only the value. That value is controlled by the [DebuggerDisplay](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) attribute.

I'd bet that the lists contain a `Tag` class with a `DebuggerDisplay` attribute that shows a GUID, perhaps the ID that appeared in the last screenshot, eg:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{ID}"]
public class Tag
{
    public Guid ID{get;set;}
    //...
}
```

The Watch window will display the contents of the `ID` property in the `Value` column and the actual type `Tag` in the `Type` column.

The `ID` of the Tag may be the same, but the contents may be different, resulting in a different hash code. Equals may work simply because it doesn't use the same fields that `GetHashCode()` does

Comment: Indeed, the screenshot shows a cast to `List<Tag>`, so `Tag` is the class to look at.

Comment: Thank you downvoter for dowvnoting what is the actual problem, without even an explanation! And if you think I copied someone else's comment, read them again

Comment: I think it´s a bad idea to answer a question although voting to close it (which you apparently did).

Comment: @HimBromBeere you misunderstand the rules then. This was a debugging question without code or a clear problem description.  The people that *did* take the time (30 minutes) to investigate this had to guess.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'd also say the dowvnoter misunderstands what *downvotes* are about. It means the answer is bad. Is it a bad answer?

Comment: I´d not say it´s a bad answer - which is why I didn´t downvote. All I said is that voting to close a question because of it being unclear on the one hand and guessing what it might be about on the other hand is a bad idea as it tends to give an answer based on a whrong guess.

Comment: @HimBromBeere amend your comment to `and spend the next half hour trying to find out what happened, up to the point that the OP confirmed that this was the problem, posting this as an answer,  and guessing what it might ..."`. That's what *real-life* development is most of the time - trying to understand what the customer means with an incomplete request or issue report, asking again and again until things clear upt

Comment: While I agree at least here on SO we talk about *specific, reproducable* issues. Otherwise we vote to close them as unclear or not reproducable as their unlikely to be meaningful to anyone except the OP.

Comment: @HimBromBeere read the comments again. Check the times. *After* the problem was found, I posted the answer after I saw that Marc posted his own answer. 4 minutes later the question was closed. Both my answer and Marc's are meaningful to anyone else encountering a similar problem